# wpf ComboBox: setting selectedindex to -1 does not set Text property to string.empty

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set the selectedIndex to -1 so it does not show any selection on the combo box Text property.

In my xaml this is how I have my combo box

```
  <ComboBox
    x:Name="MyFooComboBox"
    Margin="0,0,0,5"
    IsEditable="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyFooCollection}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding FooSelectionIndex,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ComboBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ComboBox.Style>
                    </ComboBox>
```

The way I see it is that if SelectedIndex is set to -1 then the text property of my combo box should be empty. In my ViewModel I set to default my FooSelectionIndex to -1 after my application doesn't need FooSelectionIndex any longer. I set up breakpoints when I set it to -1 and I can see that it is -1 and its raising a property changed. But I am still seeing the text displaying the previous choice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Setting `MyFooComboBox.SelectedIndex` to `-1` should clear the selection. If you set the `FooSelectionIndex` source property, the class where this property is defined must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the selection to be cleared.

Comment: @mm8 It does, and I don't know why this acts the way it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `MyFooComboBox.SelectedIndex` to `-1` should clear the selection. This works:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyFooCollection = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyFooComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="MyFooComboBox"
    IsEditable="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyFooCollection}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding FooSelectionIndex}" />

<Button Content="Clear" Click="Button_Click_1" />
```

If you set the `FooSelectionIndex` source property, the class where this property is defined must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the selection to be cleared.

You should not to set the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` explicitly, neither in the code or in the XAML markup.

Comment: I guess somethings can't be done from the view model. I was not doing it in the code behind. I just made an exception on this case and now it is clearing out after I set the index to -1

Comment: The view model should set `FooSelectionIndex` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event.